# Triggering a hidden button to use Fullscreen API on every page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, triggers

I want to use a hidden button to start full screen-mode by triggering this button with every page load.

Short explanation: My project is not addressed for the public web, but for a private webapp. After the login to the webapp it shall run in fullscreen-mode. My current best idea to realize this, is starting fullscreen-mode on every page, because it closes every time after loading a new url.

I'm very interested of other ideas to fix this problem, but first my current code:

`fullscreen.js` (switches body into full screen):

```
function fullscreen() {
if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement
    && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
    if (document.body.requestFullscreen) {
        document.body.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.body.msRequestFullscreen) {
        document.body.msRequestFullscreen();
    }else if (document.body.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }else if (document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
} else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    }else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
} }
```

`clickButton.js` (to add eventListener to a button):

```
function clickButton(buttonId) {
if (document.getElementById(buttonId) == null
    || document.getElementById(buttonId) == undefined) {
    return;
}
if (document.getElementById(buttonId).dispatchEvent) {
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initEvent("click", true, true);
    document.getElementById(buttonId).dispatchEvent(e);
} else {
    document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
} }
```

After including scripts I want to use them like this:

```
<button id="start"></button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="fullscreen.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="clickButton.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("start").onclick = fullscreen();
    clickButton("start");
</script>
```

I tried a similar version with jQuery, but without success. I think there is a problem with eventhandler, that I don't see. Thank you for your support.

Comment: you're adding the result of your function to the onclick handler, you should remove the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Towards the end of your code:

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = fullscreen();
```

You are setting element.onclick to the return value of your function (which is nothing). What you want to do is set it to the function itself.

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = fullscreen;
```

Hmm, upon further consideration. Your `fullscreen` function should still get called during that assignment. However, the fullscreen request must be called within an event handler. So as far as I can tell, its not possible to automatically go into fullscreen mode. This is most likely a UX or security feature of browsers.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. When I click button now by myself the window switches to fullscreen-mode. Now i think there are more problems with the clickButton.js, because it doesn't work with triggering by JavaScript.

Comment: I tried to use the fullscreen function after page load, but it doesn't work with this. I think there is an "action" required.

Comment: I think your right, I've been playing around with it to no avail. good luck

Comment: `NOTE: Fullscreen requests need to be called from within an event handler or otherwise they will be denied.`[From Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Comment: Yes, you are right. My current experience of JavaScript is not that high. So, do you think that is the problem? That may be the reason, why a real click works, but clickButton.js does not work. Do someone has an idea, how i could fix this OR an other idea to hold the body in fullscreen mode, even if i load a new page inside my web app?

Comment: AFAIK there are action that require true user interaction. setting fullscreen mode in a automagic way is simply not possible. you should mark this answer as accepted and then make a new question.